# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured when trying to run a script with models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model in  Django project that I want to get data from and do things with inside a **python script**.

```
from django.db import models
from metrics.models import Chart
import django
django.setup()

p = Chart.objects.filter(dept_name="IT")
print(p)
```

anytime I try and run this I get the error

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I have tried setting a global variable for Django setting with the command

> set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=projectname.settings

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not make a Django management command? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: Try running `django.setup()` before importing any of your models